# Javascript : Get word after specific word?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get a word after specific word?

For example: I have string like this :

```
string = "Price:$20 is very cheap"
```

I want get result: $20

How can I do that with Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
var matches = /Price:(.*?) /g.exec("Price:$20 is very cheap");
if(matches.length > 1) {
    var price = matches[1];
}
else {
    // Not found
}
```

Note this will match any sequence of characters after the word *Price:*. If there is whitespace after the word price, it will break. If there is no space after $20, it will break. You need to make the rules more complex depending on your input source.

Comment: Sorry. How to do this in case string is HTML?

Comment: You can check for me? in case string has no word is "price"?  http://jsfiddle.net/7fCfa/

Comment: @happi `if(matches && matches.length > 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Split the string by : and then with space.

```
string.split(":")[1].split(" ")[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Various solutions without regular expressions :

```
var s = 'Price:$20 is very cheap'; 
var s1 = s.slice(6, s.indexOf(' '));
var s2 = s.slice(s.indexOf(':') + 1, s.indexOf(' ')); 
var s3 = s.slice(s.indexOf('$'), s.indexOf(' '));
// s1 === s2 === s3 === "$20"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'Price:$20 is very cheap';
var price = str.split(' ')[0].split(':')[1]; // $20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var matches = /Price:(\$\d+)/.exec(string)
matches[1];//"$20"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.split(":")[1].split(" ")[0]`

or else you can use combination of `str.substring();` & `str.indexOf();`.Fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PmcL3/

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular Expression is a better way, as string methods cannot return correct answers on all cases.